# onLocationChanged is never called - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get the users current location using the `LocationManager` But the `onLocationChanged` never seems to be called.

Here's my code

```
public void checkLocationService(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)MapsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Perhatian");
        dialog.setMessage("Anda harus mengaktifkan GPS pada perangkat anda untuk dapat menggunakan semua fitur yang ada. Aktifkan GPS?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Pengaturan", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                MapsActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    if (gps_enabled) {
        try {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        }

        if (lm != null)  {
            try {
                lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {

            }
        }
    }
    if (network_enabled) {
        try {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        }

        if (lm != null)  {
            try {
                lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the onLocationChanged

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    pointLatitude = l.getLatitude();
    pointLongitude = l.getLongitude();

    //Fetching username from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String username = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF, "Tidak tersedia");

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Login...", "Mohon tunggu...", true, false);
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.GET_LOCATION_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
            params.put(Config.KEY_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(pointLatitude));
            params.put(Config.KEY_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(pointLongitude));

            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

What's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code to register for location updates? You are checking if the services are supported but not subscribing to updates in the snippet you supplied.

Comment: I put `checkLocationService()` in `onCreate`
How can i register for location updates?

Comment: post your MainActivity code here.

Comment: My MapsActivity is too long

Comment: i haved register for location updates, but still not work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
first check below permission is required.


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 


Then please check that your class need to extend LocationListener

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
@Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
    longitude = arg0.getLongitude();
  }

}
```

Comment: please put Toast in side the onLocationChanged and set the latitude  and longitude  , like Toast.make(context ,"latitude :"+latitude ,Toast.*).show()

Comment: Toast not called :(

Comment: please follow link http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-get-current-latitude-and.html